# Adding bookmarks in Sublime Text 2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, bookmarks

In Sublime Text 2, I'd like to be able to bookmark a line, so I can have easy access to it.
I'm working on a 2011 iMac, and various sources tell me that the shortcut is supposed to be cmd + f2.

However, when I press that, absolutely nothing happens. It does work however, if I manually go through the Goto menu and add it. Has anyone else experienced the keyboard shortcut failing? Does anybody have any ideas of how to solve it?

Thanks.

For extra info, I think this is the relevant line in the default keybindings file.

{ "keys": ["super+f2"], "command": "toggle_bookmark" },

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The point is: `F` keys on mac are triggered with pressing `fn` key, so for this case that would work as `cmd+fn+f2`.

Comment: Since you're on a Mac, you might also consider changing your system preferences to let the Function keys behave as themselves (instead of the default 'brightness', 'volume' controls, etc.

Comment: Thanks JamieJag, I'm relatively new to the mac and I figured there was some way to default them to their F-function :)

Comment: Great answer kizu ... this worked for me ... I didn't know about the "FN" key needing to be pressed ... that solved my dilemma